Content Note Owner loses access to edit Note after an edit by other user, wanted to retain the edit access for owner
If user A creates & owns the note and later other User B updates the same content note then after the update User A will not be able to edit the same note even though User A is the owner. [This applies only when user A don't have edit access to a record where content note is created]
In this screenshot I have queried all contentVersion for one contentdcoumentId and these all are created for different update by different user.

In this screenshot I have shown Contentdocument link and this contains one record for user A as well

Problem is the moment content note is updated by any other user User A loses the edit access even though User A is the owner. I wanted to keep the edit access for User A
How do I do it ?
